# Chase Paymentech merchant account with PHP

Tags: php

I have to integrate chase paymentech Orbital with PHP, have worked with paypal and google checkout, but no clue how to integrate paymentech orbital, actually I first need to authorize(validate) the card and then have to make transaction after 30 days any help or sample code for the

thanks you

Comment: Do they not have documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have [API](http://lab.chasepaymentechxpress.com/Integration/Payment_Services/Orbital_Gateway.aspx?utm_source=chase+paymentech&utm_medium=home+page&utm_campaign=body+content&utm_content=orbital+gateway) and some integration tools, so fistly I advice you to browse [it](http://lab.chasepaymentechxpress.com/Integration/Integration_Tools.aspx?utm_source=chase+paymentech&utm_medium=integration&utm_campaign=payment+services%28obital%20gateway%29&utm_content=view+integration+tools%28CTA%29)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to IP Commerce PHP Code on Github: https://github.com/ipcommerce/Commerce-Web-Services-PHP

Full Disclosure:  I work for IP Commerce and we operate lab.chasepaymentechxpress.com on behalf of Chase Paymentech.  The code you get from lab.chasepaymentechxpress is the same as you will get from the github link above.

After you get the github code, you will need to create a project at either https://my.ipcommerce.com or mylab.chasepaymentechxpress.com (same thing) in order to get access to the sandbox environment to test.

Comment: Can you post some details about specifically what do do when you create a "project" on this site? I tried to go through this process, but all I want to do is charge credit cards. I have no idea what "Commerce Boarding" or "Online2Onsite Offer Publication" are, or why I'm required to choose them to create a project...